# Error with concurrent locks during initialization of Java VM

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jvm, locking

I have a problem with starting any java applications. For example just a simple command:

```
java -version
```

prints:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 223 in class file java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.<clinit>(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1597)
    at sun.util.locale.LocaleObjectCache.<init>(LocaleObjectCache.java:48)
    at sun.util.locale.LocaleObjectCache.<init>(LocaleObjectCache.java:44)
    at java.util.Locale$Cache.<init>(Locale.java:676)
    at java.util.Locale$Cache.<init>(Locale.java:675)
    at java.util.Locale.<clinit>(Locale.java:411)
    at java.lang.String.toLowerCase(String.java:2524)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:377)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:302)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:325)
    at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.fileToEncodedURL(ParseUtil.java:272)
    at sun.misc.Launcher.getFileURL(Launcher.java:460)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.getExtURLs(Launcher.java:192)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.<init>(Launcher.java:164)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader$1.run(Launcher.java:148)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader$1.run(Launcher.java:142)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.getExtClassLoader(Launcher.java:141)
    at sun.misc.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:71)
    at sun.misc.Launcher.<clinit>(Launcher.java:57)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1489)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1474)
```

This behavior started after I installed Liferay, so I think it might be that some limit of concurrent locks have been exceeded, but I could not google any information on this.

The computer restart solved it, but I still wonder what really caused the behavior and how could it be solved without restarting.

The API docs at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html didn't help neither.

About the system:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1075      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1075      manual mode
```

Comment: This looks like it could be a bad install; the JVM is complaining that it couldn't read a `.class` file for one of he jdk classes. Have you done anything tricky with regard to installing different JVMs?

Comment: No, everything was ok until I installed Liferay. The computer restart solved it, but still I wonder why I couldn't get any info on this error.